# show that $D_{2n}=\left \langle a,b \mid a^2=e,b^n=e,aba^{-1}=b^{-1} \right \rangle$ is nilpotent iff $n$ is power of 2.

Tags: finite-groups

show that $D_{2n}=\left \langle a,b \mid a^2=e,b^n=e,aba^{-1}=b^{-1} \right \rangle$ is nilpotent iff $n$ is power of $2$.

please help me how should start and proceed,any guide or hint will be great,thanks.

Comment: If $a^2 = e$, then $a = a^{-1}$, so you can write that as $aba = b^{-1}$.

Comment: See Example 4.16 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/subgpseries1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

If $n$ is not a power of $2$, there is an odd prime $p$ dividing $n$. Consider $c = b^{n/p}$, an element of order $p$. Prove that H = $\langle c , a\rangle \le D_{2n}$ is not nilpotent, by showing that $[\langle c \rangle, \langle a \rangle] = \langle c \rangle$.

Comment: @kpax, you're welcome!